# C# Garbage Collection Weird Behavior

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I have a block of code that loads a custom storage file (data.00x) and dumps it's file contents (several files...) [for this example we'll say the referenced index only contains data.001 files for export]

Example:

```
public void ExportFileEntries(ref List<IndexEntry> filteredIndex, string dataDirectory, string buildDirectory, int chunkSize)
{
    OnTotalMaxDetermined(new TotalMaxArgs(8));

    // For each set of dataId files in the filteredIndex
    for (int dataId = 1; dataId < 8; dataId++)
    {
        OnTotalProgressChanged(new TotalChangedArgs(dataId, string.Format("Exporting selected files from data.00{0}", dataId)));

        // Filter only entries with current dataId into temp index
        List<IndexEntry> tempIndex = GetEntriesByDataId(ref filteredIndex, dataId, SortType.Offset);

        // Determine the path of the data.xxx file being exported from
        string dataPath = string.Format(@"{0}\data.00{1}", dataDirectory, dataId);

        if (File.Exists(dataPath))
        {
            // Load the data.xxx into filestream
            using (FileStream dataFs = new FileStream(dataPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // Loop through filex to export
                foreach (IndexEntry indexEntry in tempIndex)
                {
                    int fileLength = indexEntry.Length;

                    OnCurrentMaxDetermined(new CurrentMaxArgs(fileLength));

                    // Set the filestreams position to the file entries offset
                    dataFs.Position = indexEntry.Offset;

                    // Read the file into a byte array (buffer)
                    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[indexEntry.Length];
                    dataFs.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);

                    // Define some information about the file being exported
                    string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(indexEntry.Name).Remove(0, 1);
                    string buildPath = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}\{2}", buildDirectory, fileExt.ToUpper(), indexEntry.Name);

                    // If needed unencrypt the data (fileBytes buffer)
                    if (XOR.Encrypted(fileExt)) { byte b = 0; XOR.Cipher(ref fileBytes, ref b); }

                    // If no chunkSize is provided, generate default
                    if (chunkSize == 0) { chunkSize = Math.Max(64000, (int)(fileBytes.Length * .02)); }

                    // If the build directory doesn't exist yet, create it.
                    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(buildPath))) { Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(buildPath)); }

                    using (FileStream buildFs = new FileStream(buildPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(buildFs, encoding))
                        {
                            for (int byteCount = 0; byteCount < fileLength; byteCount += Math.Min(fileLength - byteCount, chunkSize))
                            {
                                bw.Write(fileBytes, byteCount, Math.Min(fileLength - byteCount, chunkSize));
                                OnCurrentProgressChanged(new CurrentChangedArgs(byteCount, ""));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    OnCurrentProgressReset(EventArgs.Empty);

                    fileBytes = null;
                }
            }
        }
        else { OnError(new ErrorArgs(string.Format("[ExportFileEntries] Cannot locate: {0}", dataPath))); }
    }

    OnTotalProgressReset(EventArgs.Empty);

    GC.Collect();
}
```

The data.001 stores about 12k files, most are very small .jpg pictures etc...etc.. for about the first half of the export process the gc collects just fine, but out of nowhere toward the last half of the export process the gc just stops giving a crap.

If I don't issue `GC.Collect()` at the end of the method the tool sits at around 255mb ram, but if I do call it goes down to about 14mb. What I'm asking, is there any obvious improvements over the way I coded the method (to increase gc performance)?

Comment: GC is not deterministic; it only collects when it _has to_ (usually when there's memory pressure overall).  Is it causing a problem or are you just trying to dump memory as soon as possible?

Comment: Yea just wanna get rid of unused memory asap because this is only one of many intensive methods that may be called back to back.

Comment: The GC will collect when there is memory pressure, so what is the harm in letting it collect when it reaches that point? Are you getting out of memory exceptions on subsequent operations?

Comment: Your byte[] is going to end up in the Large Object Heap when the file contains >= 80,000 bytes.  Sure, it doesn't give much of a crap about the LOH.

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem that isn't there.